# How to prevent the insertion of a tab if one already exists?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

My problem is simple all i need to do is to prevent the insertion of a tab ia one already exists

**Problem:** I have a search bar in which when the user inputs a name the results are wrapped in a div with class`.result_container_2` , now when the user clicks on this tab , a tab is inserted in another div with class `.selected_recipients` . Now i want the script to detect if the tab has already been inserted I've already tried it with `.each()` but with no luck

**The script:** below is the current script which generates the tab

```js
$(document).on('click', ".result_container_2", function() {
  var to_disp = $(this).data('recipient_disp');
  var to_show = $(this).data('recipient_show');
  var rel = $(this).attr('rel'); //the current account

  if (to_disp != rel) { //if the clicked tab is not the current account
    var a = $(".selected_recipients").children().length;
    var b = a++;
    $(".selected_recipients").show().append('<span class="recipient_tab" id="' + b + '" data-recipient="' + to_disp + '"><span style="display:block;float:left;">' + to_show + '</span><span class="recipient_remove">x</span></span>');
    $(".display_found_query_cont_mess_drawer").hide();
  }

});

//---for removing recipient----
$(document).on('click', ".recipient_remove", function() {
  $(this).parent(".recipient_tab").remove();

  if ($(".selected_recipients").children().length == 0) {
    $(".selected_recipients").hide();
  }
})
```

```css
/*-------recipients tabs -------*/

.selected_recipients {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 5px 0px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #CCC;
  width: 100%;
}
.recipient_tab {
  float: left;
  display: block;
  padding: 4px;
  margin-left: 5px;
  border-radius: 2px;
  -moz-border-radius: 2px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 2;
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(#777, #666);
  background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#777), to(#666));
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(#777, #666);
  background-image: -o-linear-gradient(#777, #666);
  background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(#777, #666);
  background-image: linear-gradient(#777, #666);
}
.recipient_remove {
  padding: 2px;
  float: left;
  display: block;
  margin-left: 5px;
  border-radius: 2px;
  -moz-border-radius: 2px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 2;
  background-color: #C0C0C0;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="selected_recipients"></div>

<div class="result_container_2" rel="test" data-recipient_disp="mark" data-recipient_show="mark">mark</div>

<div class="result_container_2" rel="test" data-recipient_disp="mark1" data-recipient_show="mark1">mark1</div>

<div class="result_container_2" rel="test" data-recipient_disp="test" data-recipient_show="test">test **the tab with this name wont be created**</div>
```

how do i accomplish it

Comment: cookies can be used..

Comment: @reenleedr nope as much i would love to cookies are not an option i have to use jquery

Comment: can you explain rel and current account

Comment: @reenleedr well the current account unique identifier is stored in the rel attribute

Comment: okey why are you declaring two variables to_disp and to_show both have same value

Comment: @reenleedr the to_show includes the name of the account which is visible to everyone but the to_disp includes the name which unique to each account . for the simplification of the problem the two variables have the same value but in reality the two names are different. 2 to_show values may be same but never 2 to_disp values

Comment: hey i got answer for what you want .. please give me few min to type..

Comment: Check if my answer works..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this : [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/mt382861/gmLLtm3x/)

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $(document).on('click', ".result_container_2", function() {
        var to_disp = $(this).data('recipient_disp');
        var to_show = $.trim($(this).data('recipient_show'));
        var rel = $(this).attr('rel'); 

        if (to_disp != rel && !$('.selected_recipients .recipient_tab[data-recipient="'+to_show+'"]').length) 
        { 
            var a = $(".selected_recipients").children().length;
            var b = a++;
            $(".selected_recipients").show().append('<span class="recipient_tab" id="' + b + '" data-recipient="' + to_disp + '"><span style="display:block;float:left;">' + to_show + '</span><span class="recipient_remove">x</span></span>');
            $(".display_found_query_cont_mess_drawer").hide();
        }

    });

    $(document).on('click', ".recipient_remove", function() {
        $(this).parent(".recipient_tab").remove();
        if ($(".selected_recipients").children().length == 0){
            $(".selected_recipients").hide();
        }
    })
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can acheive this by iterating through the existing tabs and checking whether `to_show` exists, if we find a match set `exists=true;`

```
exists = false;
    $.each($('.recipient_tab'),function(index,element){
          if($(element).attr('data-recipient') == to_disp){
             exists = true;
          }
    })



  if(!exists){
    $(".selected_recipients").show().append('<span class="recipient_tab" id="' + b + '" data-recipient="' + to_disp + '"><span style="display:block;float:left;">' + to_show + '</span><span class="recipient_remove">x</span></span>');
    }
```

Comment: the to_show may be repeated but the to_disp is the one that is unique

Comment: nope didnt work and now im getting a new error `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot use 'in' operator to search for '13' in .recipient_tab `

Answer (score 1):

See if this works

```
if (to_disp != rel) { //if the clicked tab is not the current account
var a = $(".selected_recipients").children().length;
var b = a++;

var present=false;
var i=0;
while(i<b)
{
if($('#'+i).data('recipient') == to_disp)
present=true;
i++;
}
if(present)
return;

$(".selected_recipients").show().append('<span class="recipient_tab" id="' + b + '" data-recipient="' + to_disp + '"><span style="display:block;float:left;">' + to_show + '</span><span class="recipient_remove">x</span></span>');
$(".display_found_query_cont_mess_drawer").hide();
}
```

Comment: yes an awesome effort but simplified to this `exists = false;
   $('.recipient_tab').each(function(){
   if($(this).attr('data-recipient') == to_disp){
      exists = true;
   }
   })
   if(!exists)
   {
    $(".selected_recipients").show().append('<span class="recipient_tab" data-recipient="'+to_disp+'"><span style="display:block;float:left;">'+to_show+'</span><span class="recipient_remove"></span></span>');
    $(".display_found_query_cont_mess_drawer").hide();
   }`